# Как заставить счетчик работать Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Допустим у меня есть текст, который называется "Шаг 1"
Мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, к называнию текста "Шаг 1" добавлялась единичка, то есть "Шаг 2". Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var x = document.querySelector('#button');
var i = 0;
x.addEventListener('click', function() {
  i++;
  document.querySelector('#step').innerHTML = i;
});
```

```html
Step <span id='step'>0</span>

<button id="button">Clickme!</button>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!))))

Answer (score 3):

Либо искать число с помощью *регулярных выражений*, если нету возможности использовать отдельный *блок для цифры*.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var num = $('p').text().match(/\d+/g); // Нашли текст и изъяли число по регулярке
  $('p').text('Шаг ' + ++num);           // Обновили текст в блоке
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Шаг 15</p>
<button>Следующий шаг</button>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!))))